# Regular expression to replace everything but alphabets

Tags: java, regex

What would be a concise regular regular expression to remove everything from a string that is not an alphabet

```
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int T=0; 
    try{
        T= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        while(T>0)
                String input=br.readLine();
                **String res= input.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]"," " );**
                System.out.println(res);
```

Also tried

```
      input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]]"," " )
```

Neither of them is replacing anything from the input string.The input string remains just as it was

Edit:

```
         input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]"," " )  //works well
         input.replaceAll("^[a-zA-Z]"," " )  //replaces first char of string
```

Comment: and Strings are immutable so you get a new string.

Comment: Capitalize the second Z.

Comment: Please don't use ranges to replace generic categories of characters; you cannot count on the range including all the characters you want (or not including some you don't).  You should use **\p{Alpha}** for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]"," " );
^^^^^^^                          ^ ^
```

You need to make the `input` reference point to the String object returned by the `replaceAll` method to get the changed string as Strings are immutable.

The range `A-z` is not something you want. You need `A-Z`.

Also you have an extra `]` in your pattern.

[**See it**](http://ideone.com/Ra2i1r)

Comment: Ranges are just *so* wrong for this.  Do you know what locale is in use?  Do you know if accented characters are going to be included in that range?  Use classes.

Comment: @itsbruce does accented characters are included in those classes?

Answer (score 3):

`input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]","")` is a new string in String constant pool and you don't set your string with this new content. Use this please:

```
input = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-z]","");
```

Comment: I just meant that the expression is not working.I edited the question now.If the expression is correct how am i still getting just the same line i feed in